# Sorting dates in Kendo Grid Angular

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to sort the dates in Kendo Grid Angular?
Kendo gird taking the date values as string and sorts it

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure the grid's `dataSource` property, you should be defining the `schema`. If you set the schema's model's field's type to `date` then you should get the expected results.

For example:

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    transport: {
      read: "https://my-api/my-endpoint"
    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          Date: { type: "date" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  sortable: true,
  columns: [
    { field: "Date", title: "Date", format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" }
  ]
});
```

Demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/ugItIKob

---

**Update**

You indicated that you needed an Angular example. In this situation, define the property representing the date field as a Date and format it in template using the date pipe.

For example:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" [sortable]="true">
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductId" title="ID"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name"></kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Cost" title="Price">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                    {{ dataItem.Cost | currency:'USD':'symbol' }}
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="PurchaseDate" title="Date">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                    {{ dataItem.PurchaseDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public gridData: IProduct[] = [
    {
      ProductId: 1,
      ProductName: 'Chai',
      Cost: 18,
      PurchaseDate: new Date('2022-08-03'),
    },
    {
      ProductId: 2,
      ProductName: 'Chang',
      Cost: 19,
      PurchaseDate: new Date('2023-08-03'),
    },
    {
      ProductId: 3,
      ProductName: 'Aniseed Syrup',
      Cost: 10,
      PurchaseDate: new Date('2021-08-17'),
    },
  ];
}

export interface IProduct {
  ProductId?: number;
  ProductName?: string;
  Cost?: number;
  PurchaseDate?: Date;
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-metwta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can you give me in angular(javascript) instead of JQuery?

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question